# Error when writing a function in Javascript that will assign a number to Array indexes and add them together, returning the total

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to write a function that will look through an array populated by strings that are grades ("average", "above average", etc.) and assign each index a number value, then add all the values into 1 score and return that score.  I am getting an error however, and I am not sure why.  Here is the function:

```
function score(unitArray){
   for(i=1,i<=unitArray.length,i++){
      var unitScore;
     if (unitArray[i]="Abysmal"){
        unitScore=unitScore+2;
     }
     else if (unitArray[i]="Below Average"){
        unitScore=unitScore+4;
     }
     else if (unitArray[i]="Average"){
        unitScore=unitScore+6;
     }
     else if (unitArray[i]="Above Average"){
        unitScore=unitScore+8;
     }
     else if (unitArray[i]="Exemplary"){
        unitScore=unitScore+12;
     }
     else{
        unitScore=unitScore;
     }
  };
  console.log(unitScore);
};
```

And it is giving me this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Your `for` loop has the wrong syntax, semicolons to separate, not commas.

Comment: You also probably want `unitScore` defined outside of the `for` loop, and you probably want to iterate from `0 upto, but not including unitArray.length`, and `===` for comparison instead of `=`, which is assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `for` loop  uses semicolons between its sections, not commas

```
for(i=1;i<=unitArray.length;i++)
```

not

```
for(i=1,i<=unitArray.length,i++)
```

Also, you're using the wrong syntax for equality. In javascript a single equals sign assigns a variable and 2 (or 3) check for equality.

So

```
if (unitArray[i]==="Abysmal"){
```

not

```
if (unitArray[i]="Abysmal"){
```

Finally, you're (probably) skipping the first element in your array, as arrays are zero-based in javascript.

Comment: wow, I feel dumb.  Thank you for your help.  This is all really new to me still so I suppose these seem like pretty silly mistakes.  Fixed my syntax and it worked well.

Comment: @MPe - everything's easy when you know how :) We all learned once.

Answer (score 0):

`for(i=1,i<=unitArray.length,i++){`

should be

`for(i=1;i<=unitArray.length;i++){`

Answer (score 0):

Intialize the varialble, and in if codintion use `===`

```
var unitScore=0;
```

for loop should be

```
for(i=1,i<=unitArray.length,i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

In for loops, the terms i=... i<=... i++ are separated by semicolons, not commas.

There were a number of other small things wrong, which I have corrected here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kp1197/L2h7eohh/2/

```
function score(unitArray){
  var unitScore = 0.0;
  for(var i=0;i<=unitArray.length;i++){
    if (unitArray[i]==="Abysmal"){
     unitScore=unitScore+2;
    }
    else if (unitArray[i]==="Below Average"){
      unitScore=unitScore+4;
    }
    else if (unitArray[i]==="Average"){
      unitScore=unitScore+6;
    }
    else if (unitArray[i]==="Above Average"){
      unitScore=unitScore+8;
    }
    else if (unitArray[i]==="Exemplary"){
      unitScore=unitScore+12;
    }
  };
  console.log(unitScore);
};

score(["Abysmal","Average","Exemplary"])
```